# Outlook Calendar API is incrementing the hours on its own

Tags: php, rest, outlook-calendar

I am working with PHP and `Outlook Calendar REST API`, I am able to create the events just fine except that the date I give API to create an events is getting incremented by 11 hours and something is wrong with end_date also, for example if i am telling the API to create the event from `2014-03-31T15:00:00-0000` to `2014-03-31T16:00:00-0000` it ends up creating the event from `2014-04-01T02:00:00+1100` to `2014-04-01T02:30:00+1100`

This is what my API URL looks like

```
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/9898ef90931244e8/events?name=testing_event&description=event_description&start_time=2014-03-31T15:00:00-0000&end_time=2014-03-31T16:00:00-0000&access_token=token-goes-here&method=POST
```

if I remove the `-0000` at the end, i get the following error

```
{
   "error": {
      "code": "request_parameter_invalid", 
      "message": "The value of input parameter 'start_time' isn't valid. The expected formats for this parameter are the following: '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z', '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', '1970-01-01 00:00:00Z'. In all cases, 'Z' is interchangeable with a time zone offset of the form: '+00:00', '-00:00', '+0000' or '-0000'."
   }
}
```

I will really appreciate any help as I have spent days trying to fix this and I am pretty much out of all ideas..

Comment: Most likely because you havn't taken the timezone in consideration?!

Comment: @Dieter isn't adding `-0000` considered as a timezone?

Comment: I think it should be, but then again, something that doesn't work from Microsoft doesn't suprise me anymore..

Comment: created another event for `start_date: 2014-05-11T12:00:00-08:00` and `end_date=2014-05-11T12:30:00-08:00`. Outlook Calendar API created it for `start_time: 2014-05-12T06:00:00+1000` and `end_time: 2014-05-12T06:30:00+1000`. I am so damn frustrated now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while ago I posted this question at MSDN Forum and forgot about it, today i visited the question and this is the [reply](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f902994b-f8cb-4d5b-a763-43f3d10ea2ce/outlook-rest-api-adding-event-date-issue?forum=messengerconnect) I got from Outlook team explaining how to understand UTC timezone, I hope this helps someone out there stuck at the same problem and I wish they included this in their documentation. This fixed the problem I was having

---

> *The ISO 8601 format for dates can be a bit confusing.  What you're seeing in your response is actually correct.  The calendar service
>   takes your date and maps it to the time zone of the user.
>
> "2014-03-31T15:00:00-0000" means 3 PM on March 31, 2014, with an
>   adjustment of 0 hours and 0 minutes to translate to UTC time.  In
>   other words, this basically IS UTC time.  The calendar service then
>   translates this into the local time zone of the user for whom you are
>   creating the event.     "2014-04-01T02:00:00+1100" means 2 AM on April
>   1, 2014, for whatever time zone your user is in.  To translate back to
>   UTC, you need to SUBTRACT the offset from the local time.  So 2 AM,
>   April 1, 2014 in your time maps to 11 hours earlier UTC, which is 3 PM
>   March 31, 2014 (what you entered).
>
> If you're using Z, that means that you are essentially specifying a
>   UTC time.  So to get the desired time for your event you need to take
>   your desired time and figure out what the corresponding UTC time is. 
>   So if the UTC offset of your user is +1100 you would need to subtract
>   that offset from the local time of your event to calculate the UTC
>   time.  In your case I believe this would be 2014-03-31T04:00:00Z. This
>   is actually something that's best left to code instead of trying to
>   figure out how to do yourself.  If you take a look at the "Creating
>   Calendar Events" sample at http://isdk.dev.live.com it shows you how
>   to do this in JavaScript - maybe there's a PHP equivalent.*

---